# object object coming instead of given key and value pair in javascrip object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have on each function inside which I am creating one object and trying to access object value but it's giving object object in return instead of it's key and value

```js
var _field = [0, 1, 2, 3]
$(_field).each(function() {
  var abc = { id: '1' };
  console.log(abc);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: As you can see, when clicking on the `Run code snippet` button above, the object is correctly printed to the console. My guess is that your original problem does not actually involve `console.log`, but you may be trying to show the object in the HTML, or somewhere else (`alert()`?). Is this the case? If so, please clarify your question, with an example that actually reproduces the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass an object to the console log, it will implicitly call the toString method.  For objects, it is best to use JSON.stringify() instead:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(abc))
```

Comment: _"When you pass an object to the console log, it will implicitly call the toString method"_. Have you ever tried to `console.log` an Object?